# Prevent a debug_zval_dump memory overflow

Tags: php

I am implementing a cache of PHP objects. It's ok to release an object from the cache only if there are no other references to that object, since it will be a different instance if it gets recreated. And obviously this might cause problems when we're comparing  the recreated instance to other references to the original instance.

I have the following code, found (and then modified) on StackOverflow to find the number of references to an object:

```
function referenceCount($obj)
{   if (ob_get_level()) {
        $ob_started = true ;
        ob_end_flush();
    } else $ob_started = false ;
    ob_start();
    debug_zval_dump($obj);
    $dump = ob_get_clean();
    if ( $ob_started ) ob_start();
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/refcount\(([0-9]+)/', $dump, $matches);

    $count = $matches[1]??3;

    //3 references are added, including when calling debug_zval_dump()
    return $count - 3;
}
```

However: my objects reference each other as parents and children in an intricate way and this makes the code actually crash because it runs out of memory on  `debug_zval_dump($obj)`. The object dump is just too big (the objects themselves are not, it's the cross referencing).

I've googled the heck out of it, but cannot find a way to either:

1. Ignore the output of `debug_zval_dump` after the first 256 bytes (something with chunk size in the ob_start() ?)
2. Get the zval without the object dump (cannot install xdebug at the moment, but `xdebug_debug_zval` seems to dump the object recursively as well as far as I can see, not sure tho)
3. Find another way to count the number of references to an object in PHP.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: May weakmap can help here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.weakmap.php mostly this part *if at any point the only remaining reference to an object is the key of a WeakMap, the object will be garbage collected and removed from the WeakMap*

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know of Weak references. Thanks, this sends me in the right way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foobar put me on the right track and also gave me a way to prevent a memory overflow with var_dump, var_export and debug_zval_dump. This is to use WeakReferences as parent references. This stops the recursion in printing, plus it has the additional benefit of not spiking the reference count to instances.

I now use this:

```
trait weakParent {
    private array $parentObjectRefs ;

    private function weakParent(object $parent, string $propertyName='parent') {
        $this->parentObjectRefs[$propertyName] = WeakReference::create($parent);
    }

    // Have your own __get? Let it call __getParent() to see if the parent is needed
    function __get(string $propName) {
        if (! array_key_exists($propName, $this->parentObjectRefs)) trigger_error("Error in ".__CLASS__. ": unknown property $propName", E_USER_ERROR);
        return $this->__getParent($propName);
    }
    function __getParent(string $propName): ?object {
        if (isset($this->parentObjectRefs[$propName])) return $this->parentObjectRefs[$propName]->get() ;
        return null ;
    }
}
```

and this can be used as follows:

```
class xxx {
    use weakParent ;
    
    function __construct(parentClass $parent) {
       $this->weakParent($parent, 'parent') ;
       // this->parent now exists
    }

    // this part is needed ONLY if you need a custom __get function, remove otherwise
    function __get(string $prop): mixed {
        if ( $r = $this->__getParent() ) return $r ;
        // here your custom code
    }
}
```

If you now do a `$obj = new xxx($parentObject)` and then a `var_dump($obj);`, the parent does not get displayed, preventing recursion and a lot of useless information.

The reason I am using `__get()` and not a method is to be compatible with existing code, but I also prefer it being (or rather faking) a property instead of a method.

Comment: $this->weakParent() can also be used to define grandparents and siblings if wanted/needed.

Comment: And lastly: don't use a weakParent if your only reference to that parent is in the children (i.e. if you have a child class creating a parent - it happens!).